# Getting Unique Values in Multidimensional Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array similar to this:

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "32" [1]=> string(2) "67" [2]=> string(19) "2013-07-15 15:56:28" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(4) "Fail"}
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "32" [1]=> string(2) "89" [2]=> string(19) "2013-09-15 13:50:34" [3]=> string(1) "2" [4]=> string(4) "Pass"}
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "37" [1]=> string(2) "55" [2]=> string(19) "2013-07-15 16:36:12" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(4) "Fail"}
array(5) { [0]=> string(2) "39" [1]=> string(2) "92" [2]=> string(19) "2013-08-15 15:46:20" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(4) "Pass"}
```

The first value displays a content ID, the second a score, the third a date, the fourth an attempt number (no limit), and the fifth a result. I want to print these values in the browser, but if there is more than one attempt, I only want to print the one with the highest score. I can't seem to get it working, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The way you can achieve this is:

- 1st: Group the results by content ID.
- 2nd: Descending Order the sub-array by score using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
- 3rd: Display the 1st sub-array to user for each content ID.